# Stuck on how to get the index's value from an array of a user defined value

Tags: c, arrays, input, scanf

I'm trying to write C code where the user inputs 10 values and the index, and the output should display the index's value from the 10 values set by the user.

The problem statement:

Your grandparents gave you a fantastic cooking recipe but you can never remember how much of each ingredient you have to use! There are 10 ingredients in the recipe and the quantities needed for each of them are given as input (in grams). Your program must read 10 integers (the quantities needed for each of the ingredients, in order) and store them in an array. It should then read an integer which represents an ingredient's ID number (between 0 and 9), and output the corresponding quantity

Example Input:

500 180 650 25 666 42 421 1 370 211

3

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int ingred[9];
int readValue = 0;
int ID;
for(int i = 0; i < 9;i++){
    scanf("%d %d", &readValue,&ID);
    ingred[i] = readValue;

}
printf("%d",ingred[ID]);
return 0;
}
```

My output is always 0. Doesn't the scanf() function read the next line of code after the user presses "enter"? Please help.

Comment: what did you see in readValue and ID when you used your debugger?

Comment: It appears that you may be misunderstanding the question. It seems that the quantities are provided on one line of input (to be then stored into an array), and then an index is provide on the next line. I think you're supposed to output the quantity at the given index (index of the array you built from the first line of input).

Comment: My bad, I meant to say it displays the value at that index, which was my intention with: printf("%d",ingred[ID]);

Comment: @VictorNovelo: Then please update your question, including the title.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a requirement to read all of the quantities from a single line? Because that can be a little tricky to perform with scanf.
You could iterate trough a loop and get all of the quantities one by one, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int ingredients [10];
  int newQuantity = 0;
  int ingredientId;
  int index;

  for (index = 0; index < 10; index++)
  {
      printf ("Enter quantity #%d: ", index);
      scanf ("%d", &newQuantity);
      ingredients [index] = newQuantity;

  }

  printf ("Enter the ID: ");
  scanf ("%d", &ingredientId);
  printf ("Quantity: %d\n", ingredients [ingredientId]);

  return 0;
}
```

On your code you tried to read a pair of integer values nine times in your loop. That's also something to note: despite array indexes beginning at 0, when you declare an array, the value between brackets is the number of elements of the array, not the index of the last element.

Comment: Thank you, it turns out that where the error was. I was taking 9 ingredients instead of 10. Much appreciated :)

Comment: Note, this input routine is horribly fragile. One slip of the keyboard and an `'r'` tapped instead of `'5'` and it is toast. Always check the **return** of `scanf` and handle the 3-cases (1) `EOF`; (2) a *matching* or *input* failure (and in case of a *matching* failure remove the unmatched characters from your input buffer); and finally (3) handle the good-input case.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int i = 0;
    int entry;
    int index = 0;
    int array[10];
    for(i = 0; i <10; i++){
        scanf("%d", &entry);
        array[index] = entry;
        index = index + 1;
    }
    scanf("%d", &index);
    printf("%d", array[index]);
    return 0;
}
```

Try this.